# vnc dynamic runtime firewall ports >= 5901

Tags: centos, rhel, firewall, vnc, firewalld

In RHEL/Centos 7, TigerVNC-Server only needs 5901/tcp for desktop:1, then 5902/tcp for desktop:2, and so on.
*I think any VNC-server would operate the same way.*

- If no one has typed `vncerver` for themself, I would like the firewall to block all ports >= 5901
- as more users do `vncserver` I want those tcp ports 5901..? to be allowed based on desktop:1 to desktop:?
- when a user does `vncserver -kill :?` I then want that tcp port to be removed from the run time firewall and that port then blocked.

Is something like this possible to do, if so, how?

Could a **wrapper** script named `vncserver` be written to preempt the running of the real `/usr/bin/vncserver`, and in doing do issue the proper `firewall-cmd` to make such a thing happen and then perform the real `/usr/bin/vncserver`?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `Xvnc -inetd -query localhost` as a unprivileged non-root user out of systemd or xinetd.  You need a login manager like gdm or lightdm that listens for XDMCP on the loopback interface.

That way you can always connect to the same port and create a new desktop session.  Of course, if you disconnect, it ends the session.